# How to do to connect filebeat to kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, https, kibana, filebeat

How do I connect filebeat to kibana (accessed with https instead of http)?
Because when I try `$ sudo filebeat setup -e` this error appears: (I use version 8.3.2 for kibana elastic and filebeat)

```
Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET re  quest to https://192.168.37.2:5601/api/status fails: fail to execute the HTTP GE  T request: Get "https://192.168.37.2:5601/api/status": x509: certificate signed   by unknown authority. Response:
```

Answer (score 2):

## Tldr;

You must be using custom generated certificates.

## To solve (2 solutions)

### (1) Trust those certificates

You can do this by adding te certificates to the configuration `filebeat.yml`

```yaml
setup.kibana.ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/client/ca.pem"]
setup.kibana.ssl.certificate: "/etc/client/cert.pem"
setup.kibana.ssl.key: "/etc/client/cert.key
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/setup-kibana-endpoint.html#_setup_kibana_ssl_enabled
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-ssl.html

### (2) Ignore the certificate verification:

You can do so by using adding this in your `filebeat.yml`

```yaml
ssl.verification_mode: none
```

Comment: when i try the first solution of adding the certificates it appear to me this errors :2errors: open /etc/client/cert.pem: no such file or directory /etc/client/cert.pem; open /etc/client/ca.pem: no such file or directory reading <nil> accessing 'setup.kibana' (source:'/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml')","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: 2 errors: open /etc/client/cert.pem: no such file or directory /etc/client/cert.pem; open /etc/client/ca.pem: no such file or directory reading <nil> accessing 'setup.kibana' (source:'/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml')

Comment: Well have you put the certs files in those places ?

You can try the second solutions if you don't know where to find those files

Comment: where i will put them ? where them places plz?

Comment: In the `filebeat.yml` file

Comment: i did but still not working

Comment: I had a similar issue when trying to setup dashboards in filebeat. It worked for me with this command. `metricbeat setup -E setup.kibana.host=https://elastic:changeme@kibana:5601 -E setup.kibana.ssl.verification_mode=none --dashboards`. Of course you need to change url, username, password accordingly